# Linux Xlib erroneous alpha handling

Tags: c, linux, x11, transparent, xlib

I have two piece of source code copied from stackoverflow and GitHub, which demonstrates alpha channel handling on an Xlib form. First is simple Xlib, next is OpenGL. However at me, it's working erroneously.

If i set the alpha channel value to 0, then any colour should be fully transparent, not just black, but the closer the colour is to white, the less the alpha channel works. If i set the color to white, then the window is entirely ignoring the alpha channel. 0x00808080 is semi transparent.

I have no idea what i am doing wrong, can anybody tell me what is the problem? Maybe the problem is with my machine?

Here is the first code snippet:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(display, DefaultScreen(display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);

    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);
    attr.border_pixel = 0;
    attr.background_pixel = 0x00ffffff;

    Window win = XCreateWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0, 300, 200, 0, vinfo.depth, InputOutput, vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);
    XSelectInput(display, win, StructureNotifyMask);
    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, win, 0, 0);

    Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, win, &wm_delete_window, 1);

    XMapWindow(display, win);

    int keep_running = 1;
    XEvent event;

    while (keep_running) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);

        switch(event.type) {
            case ClientMessage:
                if (event.xclient.message_type == XInternAtom(display, "WM_PROTOCOLS", 1) && (Atom)event.xclient.data.l[0] == XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 1))
                    keep_running = 0;

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(display, win);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the second:

```
/*
      ____      _____
    /\__  \   /\  ___\
    \/__/\ \  \ \ \__/_
        \ \ \  \ \____ \
        _\_\ \  \/__/_\ \
      /\ _____\  /\ _____\
      \/______/  \/______/

   Copyright (C) 2011 Joerg Seebohn

   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program demonstrates how an X11 window with OpenGL support
   can be drawn transparent.

   The title bar and window border drawn by the window manager are
   drawn opaque.
   Only the background of the window which is drawn with OpenGL
         glClearColor( 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7) ;
         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) ;
   is 30% transparent.

   Compile it with: 
     gcc -std=gnu99 -o test testprogram.c -lX11 -lGL
*/
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Display    * display = XOpenDisplay( 0 ) ;
   const char * xserver = getenv( "DISPLAY" ) ;

   if (display == 0)
   {
      printf("Could not establish a connection to X-server '%s'\n", xserver ) ;
      exit(1) ;
   }

   // query Visual for "TrueColor" and 32 bits depth (RGBA)
   XVisualInfo visualinfo ;
   XMatchVisualInfo(display, DefaultScreen(display), 32, TrueColor, &visualinfo);

   // create window
   Window   win ;
   GC       gc ;
   XSetWindowAttributes attr ;
   attr.colormap   = XCreateColormap( display, DefaultRootWindow(display), visualinfo.visual, AllocNone) ;
   attr.event_mask = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask ;
   attr.background_pixmap = None ;
   attr.border_pixel      = 0 ;
   win = XCreateWindow(    display, DefaultRootWindow(display),
                           50, 300, 400, 100, // x,y,width,height : are possibly opverwriteen by window manager
                           0,
                           visualinfo.depth,
                           InputOutput,
                           visualinfo.visual,
                           CWColormap|CWEventMask|CWBackPixmap|CWBorderPixel,
                           &attr
                           ) ;
   gc = XCreateGC( display, win, 0, 0) ;

   // set title bar name of window
   XStoreName( display, win, "Transparent Window with OpenGL Support" ) ;

   // say window manager which position we would prefer
   XSizeHints sizehints ;
   sizehints.flags = PPosition | PSize ;
   sizehints.x     = 50 ;  sizehints.y = 300 ;
   sizehints.width = 400 ; sizehints.height = 100 ;
   XSetWMNormalHints( display, win, &sizehints ) ;
   // Switch On >> If user pressed close key let window manager only send notification >>
   Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom( display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0) ;
   XSetWMProtocols( display, win, &wm_delete_window, 1) ;

   { 
      // change foreground color to brown
      XColor    xcol ;
      xcol.red   = 153 * 256 ;   // X11 uses 16 bit colors !
      xcol.green = 116 * 256 ;
      xcol.blue  = 65  * 256 ;
      XAllocColor( display, attr.colormap, &xcol) ;
      XGCValues gcvalues ;
      gcvalues.foreground = xcol.pixel ;
      XChangeGC( display, gc, GCForeground, &gcvalues) ;
   }

   // create OpenGL context
   GLXContext glcontext = glXCreateContext( display, &visualinfo, 0, True ) ;
   if (!glcontext)
   {
      printf("X11 server '%s' does not support OpenGL\n", xserver ) ;
      exit(1) ;
   }
   glXMakeCurrent( display, win, glcontext ) ;

   // now let the window appear to the user
   XMapWindow( display, win) ;

   int isUserWantsWindowToClose = 0 ;

   while( !isUserWantsWindowToClose )
   {
      int  isRedraw = 0 ;

      /* XPending returns number of already queued events.
       * If no events are queued XPending sends all queued requests to the X-server
       * and tries to read new incoming events. */

      while( XPending(display) > 0 )
      {
         // process event
         XEvent   event ;
         XNextEvent( display, &event) ;

         switch(event.type)
         {  // see 'man XAnyEvent' for a list of available events
         case ClientMessage:
                  // check if the client message was send by window manager to indicate user wants to close the window
                  if (  event.xclient.message_type  == XInternAtom( display, "WM_PROTOCOLS", 1)
                        && event.xclient.data.l[0]  == XInternAtom( display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 1)
                        )
                  {
                     isUserWantsWindowToClose = 1 ;
                  }
                  break;
         case KeyPress:
                  if (XLookupKeysym(&event.xkey, 0) == XK_Escape)
                  {
                     isUserWantsWindowToClose = 1 ;
                  }
                  break ;
         case Expose:
                  isRedraw = 1 ;
                  break ;
         default:
               // do nothing
               break ;
         }

      }

      // ... all events processed, now do other stuff ...

      if (isRedraw)
      {  // needs redraw
         // use opengl to clear background in (transparent) light grey
         glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 0) ;
         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) ;
         glXSwapBuffers( display, win) ;
         glXWaitGL() ;
         // draw string with X11
         XDrawString( display, win, gc, 10, 20, "Hello ! ", 7) ;
      }

      // ... do something else ...

   }

   XDestroyWindow( display, win ) ; 
   win = 0 ;
   XCloseDisplay( display ) ; 
   display = 0 ;

   return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: About the redraw: You clear to (transparent) white in opengl, flip front and back, and then draw a brown string in top of it using xlib, right? If I´m correct you never blend you string with the already drawn surface (which is white regardless of alpha). To do that you need to specify a blend operation using the features provided by XRender Library.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. It's the background color, not the string.

If i set the background color's alpha channel to zero, then no matter what are the other channels containing, the background must be perfectly transparent.

Yet, if i set the other channels to other than black, then the background is not fully transparent. (The brighter the color is, the less transparent the background is.)

Comment: Ok. What do you want to have behind the background?

Comment: Nothing. What i want is equivalent result with any kind of background color if the alpha channel is zeroed out. Check the first code with background color 0. Then with background color 0xffffff. You'll see the difference.

Or, if not, then the problem is in my system.

Comment: Still not sure I get it... I´ll just type my thoughts. "Check the first code with background color 0. Then with background color 0xffffff." - You mean the "first code" is about the xlib background pixel and the second about OpenGL clear color? "What i want is equivalent result with any kind of background color if the alpha channel is zeroed out." - And by equivalent I assume black? Will multiplying the alpha with the clear color channels do it for you?

Comment: Source: http://oscomp.hu/depot/alphatest.c
Compile: gcc alphatest.c -o alphatest -lX11
Result: http://oscomp.hu/depot/t000000.png
Change line 14 to: attr.background_pixel = 0x00404040;
Result: http://oscomp.hu/depot/t404040.png
Next 0x00808080, result: http://oscomp.hu/depot/t808080.png
Next 0x00c0c0c0, result: http://oscomp.hu/depot/tc0c0c0.png
Next 0x00ffffff, result: http://oscomp.hu/depot/tffffff.png

The alpha channel was zero all along. We should got a fully transparent background, like in the first case, but with the increasing brightness, we get decreasing translucensy.

Comment: Great comment! I have no idea why it looks like that. I didn´t even think you had translucent windows in core X11. Given your images and tests I have a few suggestions. Check the RGB(A) layout of your visual using XGetVisualInfo(display, VisualRedMaskMask, ...) etc. You should check the return value XMatchVisualInfo in case it returns error (0). Hope it helps.

Comment: All the shades of grey, from black to white are composed from equal RGB values. If i would zero out any of the RGB channels instead of the alpha channel, then i would never get a grey value. It can't be a layout problem.
But just to provide what you asked: http://oscomp.hu/depot/masktest.c
And the result was "00ff0000" as it was expected. It's not a layout problem.

Comment: Interesting... I don´t have an environment for trying xlib stuff at this time so I can´t really test for myself. I also have no more clues of what to look for. Good luck finding it out.

Comment: In another topic the problem was solved:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906128/how-to-create-semi-transparent-white-window-in-xlib/
The answer was pre-multiplying the color channels with alpha.

Comment: That will almost certainly be it. If you pass about pre-multipled alpha, many routines work more efficiently, so APIs sometimes demand it.