# Draw border (frame) using xlib

Tags: c, x11, xlib

Is it possible to draw transparent window without title bar, close button, responses on mouse buttons using xlib. So just border with specific color and width? Something like [image]

this orange rectangle is what I need to create. Also I'd like to have possibility to move, resize, close and make it flicking (change border's color on timer) programatically.

I managed to create transparent window without titlebar and draw rectangles on each side of the window to make border-effect:

```
#define W_WIDTH 640
#define W_HEIGHT 480

#define X_POS 100
#define Y_POS 120
#define BORDER_WIDTH 2

Display *dpy;
Window w;

XRectangle rectangles[4] =
    {
    { X_POS, Y_POS, W_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH },
    { X_POS, Y_POS, BORDER_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT },
    { X_POS, W_HEIGHT - BORDER_WIDTH, W_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH },
    { W_WIDTH - BORDER_WIDTH, Y_POS, BORDER_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT }
    };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GC gc;
    XGCValues gcv;
    int run = 1;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);
    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);

    w = XCreateWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), X_POS, Y_POS,
                      W_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT, BORDER_WIDTH, vinfo.depth,
                      InputOutput, vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);
    XColor color;
    Colormap colormap;
    char orangeDark[] = "#FF8000";
    colormap = DefaultColormap(dpy, 0);
    XParseColor(dpy, colormap, orangeDark, &color);
    XAllocColor(dpy, colormap, &color);

    gcv.line_width = BORDER_WIDTH;
    gc = XCreateGC(dpy, w, GCLineWidth, &gcv);

    XSelectInput(dpy, w, ExposureMask);
    Atom window_type = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
    long value = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK", False);
    XChangeProperty(dpy, w, window_type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) &value, 1);
    XMapWindow(dpy, w);
    XSync(dpy, False);

    while(run)
    {
        XEvent xe;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &xe);
        switch (xe.type)
        {
            case Expose:
                XSetForeground(dpy, gc, color.pixel);
                XDrawRectangles(dpy, w, gc, rectangles, 4);
                XFillRectangles(dpy, w, gc, rectangles, 4);
                XSync(dpy, False);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(dpy, w);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```

This code works almost fine except the thing, that my orange border is semitransparent and is almost invisible on light windows:
[image]
Could you please tell how I need change my code to draw solid orange rectangles? Another variant I have is to draw transparent rectangle inside of orange window. But I didn't find any info in the Internet about how to do that.

Comment: Usually window border is handled by the Window Manager. So you probably don't want this border, instead you want a borderless window which has the rectangle inside its edges, and transparent center.

Comment: Thanks. Then the second variant should be implemented. Could you please share examples how to make transparent center inside of my orange rectangle?

Comment: I don't have such an example.

Comment: May be some links I can read to implement transparent center within my orange window?

Comment: @rudolfninja https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906128/how-to-create-semi-transparent-white-window-in-xlib

Comment: @JL2210, thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it isn't what I need...or may be it is, but I don't understand how can it solve my problem. Do you mean, that my window shouldn't be completely transparent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two main mistakes.

1. Not initializing `attr` and `gcv` to 0
2. Not using `attr.colormap` for color allocation

That should help:

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

#define W_WIDTH 640
#define W_HEIGHT 480

#define X_POS 100
#define Y_POS 120
#define BORDER_WIDTH 2

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    XRectangle rectangles[4] = {
        { X_POS, Y_POS, W_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH },
        { X_POS, Y_POS, BORDER_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT },
        { X_POS, W_HEIGHT - BORDER_WIDTH, W_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH },
        { W_WIDTH - BORDER_WIDTH, Y_POS, BORDER_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT }
    };
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XSetWindowAttributes attr = {0};
    XGCValues gcv = {0};
    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    GC gc;

    Window w;

    int run = 1;

    XMatchVisualInfo(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);

    XColor color;
    char orangeDark[] = "#FF8000";
    XParseColor(dpy, attr.colormap, orangeDark, &color);
    XAllocColor(dpy, attr.colormap, &color);

    w = XCreateWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), X_POS, Y_POS,
                      W_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT, BORDER_WIDTH, vinfo.depth,
                      InputOutput, vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);

    gcv.line_width = BORDER_WIDTH;
    gc = XCreateGC(dpy, w, GCLineWidth, &gcv);

    XSelectInput(dpy, w, ExposureMask);
    long value = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK", False);
    XChangeProperty(dpy, w, XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False),
                    XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) &value, 1);
    XMapWindow(dpy, w);
    XSync(dpy, False);

    while(run) {
        XEvent xe;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &xe);
        switch (xe.type) {
            case Expose:
                XSetForeground(dpy, gc, color.pixel);
                XDrawRectangles(dpy, w, gc, rectangles, 4);
                XFillRectangles(dpy, w, gc, rectangles, 4);
                XSync(dpy, False);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(dpy, w);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it solved my problem. One more question: is XSetBackground needed on Expose event handler? Everything works fine without this call, but may be it is needed in some purposes.

Comment: @rudolfninja No. Oh damn it, sorry, that was a leftover from my experiment. Code fixed.

Comment: Is it possible to draw that rectangle with mouse as in the  case of rubberbanding?

Comment: @kenn Sure, why not. The code would look quite a bit different though.

Comment: @hidefromkgb would you post a sample code please? Shall I ask it as a question?

Comment: @kenn For starters, please at least try doing it yourself.