# Opaque elements in transparent window in Xorg

Tags: x11, xlib, xorg, xcb

I am developing a simple X11 application with cairo and xcb.
I was wondering if there is any way to to put fully opaque elements (for example icons) in a window with a transparent background.

For the transparency I am using _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY.
I am also using the shape extension for a custom shape.

Note that I don't want a fully transparent window, but a certain opacity in the background with opaque icons/text.

This is where I create the window

```c
    const uint32_t value_mask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXMAP | XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_BORDER_PIXEL
                              | XCB_CW_OVERRIDE_REDIRECT | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK | XCB_CW_COLORMAP;

    const uint32_t event_mask = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY
                              | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_FOCUS_CHANGE
                              | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS;

    xcb_colormap_t colormap = xcb_generate_id(win->con->connection);
    xcb_create_colormap(win->con->connection, XCB_COLORMAP_ALLOC_NONE, colormap, win->con->screen->root, win->con->visual_type->visual_id);

    const uint32_t value_list[] = {
        XCB_NONE,   // back pixmap
        0x00000000, // back pixel
        0x00000000, // border pixel
        true,       // override redirect
        event_mask, // event mask
        colormap    // colormap
    };

    win->window = xcb_generate_id(win->con->connection);
    xcb_create_window(win->con->connection,
                      XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
                      win->window, win->con->screen->root,
                      win->x, win->y,
                      win->width, win->height,
                      0, // border
                      XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
                      win->con->screen->root_visual,
                      value_mask,
                      value_list);
```

This is where I create a buffer with cairo

```c
    cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height);

    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);
    cairo_set_fill_rule(cr, CAIRO_FILL_RULE_EVEN_ODD);
    cairo_set_operator(cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);

    double alpha = 0.8;

    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, alpha);
    cairo_paint(cr);
//...
```

And finally this is where I paint the window

```c
    cairo_xcb_surface_set_size(win->surface, width, height);
    xcb_clear_area(win->con->connection, false, win->window, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    cairo_set_source_surface(win->cr, surface, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(win->cr);
    cairo_show_page(win->cr);
```

Comment: _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY is not what you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906128 and my answer. You can draw normally on such window, with fully opaque or semi-transparent colours.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I actually tried your solution, however I don't know how to make it work since I am not working with the raw pixels but with cairo. I tried multiplying the alpha to the channels when setting the color, but it didn't change anything. But maybe I need to set up something with the compositor?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I added my code to make the situation clearer

Comment: Consider making it a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I know I should do it. but xcb is really too verbose. But the fact is, everything with the window works (event, mapping, etc). The only problem is transparency. If I set the backing to 0 or 0x80808080 like in your example, it still doesn't show as transparent, even tough I set the alpha in cairo. So I was wondering at this point if the compositor is at fault (using picom).

Comment: But since for _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY it still works I don't know ^

Comment: Try copying the code from the question and changing the background to 0x80808080, does it work on your system?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, as I said I tried your answer and 80808080 not worked.

Comment: I finally figured it out: My Xorg session (for whatever reasons) starts the root window with 24 bit depth (instead of 32) and I copy the depth of the root in my create_window. So setting manually 32 bit depth solves this issue. Sorry to have troubled you, your solution actually works!

Comment: "starts the root window with 24" That's normal. You shouldn't rely on the depth of the root.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI why is it normal? I actually checked with xdpyinfo and it says the default visual is 24bit, but all my windows (except the root) are 32 bit. Should I set the default visual for xorg to be 32 bit or there is a strong reason to keep 24 bit for the root? (even tough I am using a compositor)

Comment: In my case most windows but not all are 32-bit. My guess is that modern toolkits just go for the deepest visual by default, so if you run a desktop such as kde or gnome, windows from that desktop will be all 32 bit. Older programs like xterm use the default visual which is 24 bit in my case. I don't think it makes sense to change the defaults. There is no reason to.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I am using xinit with dwm, the default 24 bit visual seems to be set by the xorg server itself I think. It never once occurred to me that the visual was off so I guess I won't change it either. Thank you for all the help :p